# How to prevent user from selecting multiple radio button on each record row using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3plus rows in the json record which was displayed dynamically and everything is working fine.

A user can select a multiple radio button instead of just one radio button on each row. How do I ensure that only one radio button is selected per row using JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body> 

 <h1>Select Record using Radio button</h1>
<div id="data"></div> 

<script>

var json = [{
    "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
         "middlename": "m_doe"
}, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
        "lastName": "Smith",
           "middlename": "m_smith"
}, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Jones",
         "middlename": "m_Jones"
}];

$(document).ready(function(){
 var len = json.length;
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
              
                var firstname = json[i].firstName;
                var lastname = json[i].lastName;
                var middlename = json[i].middlename;
               

                var tr_str = "<div id='user_record'>" +
                    "<span align='center'>" + (i+1) + "</span>" +

                    "<input type='radio' id="+ lastname +">" +lastname+
                    "<input type='radio' id="+ firstname +">" +firstname+
                    "<input type='radio' id="+ middlename +">" +middlename+

                "</div><br><br>";

               $("#data").append(tr_str);
}

});





</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot showing multiple radio button selection on each row]

Comment: A radio group needs a common `name`. Browser only allows one selected with that name. Some basic research into how html radio works would have identified this for you

Comment: This should be covered in most any html radio tutorial; might want to check one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After series of comments and downvotes, I knew something is  wrong somewhere. I finally got it working.

I just updated the radio values and name variables with a unique identity `value='rec_"+ (i+1) +"' name='rec_"+ (i+1) +"'`
hence the solution below. its working now

```
            "<input type='radio' value='rec_"+ (i+1) +"' name='rec_"+ (i+1) +"' id="+ lastname +">" +lastname+
            "<input type='radio' value='rec_"+ (i+1) +"' name='rec_"+ (i+1) +"' id="+ firstname +">" +firstname+
            "<input type='radio' value='rec_"+ (i+1) +"' name='rec_"+ (i+1) +"'  id="+ middlename +">" +middlename+
```